# Magento2 - How can I display a product attribute value in Order Summary block?

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

I am trying to display a product attribute value instead of the product name.

I have found the tempplate where it is displayed: `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/item/details.html`, on line 15.

e.g. Changing `$parent.name` to `$parent.[any-attribute-code]` outputs an empty string.

How can I get the value for an attribute to display ?

Comment: I can see the fields available are selection of the ones from the "quote_item" table (not including sku which I need) but I cannot work out where which fields are included are determined

Answer (score 5):

You will have to create a plugin for that. I wanted to add product flavor to order summary. This is the way I created a plugin and achieved what I wanted.

Vendor = Sejal

Files you need to create:

1. Registration.php : app\code\Sejal\Flavor\registration.php
2. di.xml : app\code\Sejal\Flavor\etc\di.xml
3. module.xml : app\code\Sejal\Flavor\etc\module.xml
4. ConfigProviderPlugin.php : app\code\Sejal\Flavor\Plugin\ConfigProviderPlugin.php
5. details.html : copy of vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\summary\item\details.html

you can override this file in your theme like this

app\design\frontend\Vendor\themename\Magento_Checkout\web\template\summary\item\details.html

Code:
registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Sejal_Flavor',
    __DIR__
);
```

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
        <plugin name="AddAttPlug" type="Sejal\Flavor\Plugin\ConfigProviderPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Sejal_Flavor" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

ConfigProviderPlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace Sejal\Flavor\Plugin;

class ConfigProviderPlugin extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{

    public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, array $result)
    {

        $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        for($i=0;$i<count($items);$i++){

            $quoteId = $items[$i]['item_id'];
            $quote = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item')->load($quoteId);
            $productId = $quote->getProductId();
            $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
            $productFlavours = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('flavors')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);         
            if($productFlavours == 'No' || $productFlavours == 'NA'){
                $productFlavours = '';
            }
            $items[$i]['flavor'] = $productFlavours;
        }
        $result['totalsData']['items'] = $items;
        return $result;
    }

}
```

details.html

Copy vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\summary\item\details.html in theme and add

```
<div class="product-item-flavor" data-bind="text: $parent.flavor"></div>
```

below

```
<strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="text: $parent.name"></strong>
```

That's it! 
Hope it helps!

**UPDATE**

Replace the code in ConfigProviderPlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace Sejal\Flavor\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface as QuoteItemRepository;


class ConfigProviderPlugin extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    private $checkoutSession;
    private $quoteItemRepository;
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
        QuoteItemRepository $quoteItemRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->quoteItemRepository = $quoteItemRepository;
    }


    public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, array $result)
    {
            $quoteId = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId();            
            if ($quoteId) {            
                $itemOptionCount = count($result['totalsData']['items']);
                $quoteItems = $this->quoteItemRepository->getList($quoteId);
                $isbnOptions = array();
                foreach ($quoteItems as $index => $quoteItem) {
                    $quoteItemId = $quoteItem['item_id'];
                    $isbnOptions[$quoteItemId] = $quoteItem['isbn'];               
                }

                for ($i=0; $i < $itemOptionCount; $i++) {
                $quoteParentId = $result['totalsData']['items'][$i]['item_id'];
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $productId = $result['quoteItemData'][$i]['product']['entity_id'];
                $productObj = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

                $productFlavours = $productObj->getResource()->getAttribute('flavors')->getFrontend()->getValue($productObj);         
                if($productFlavours == 'No' || $productFlavours == 'NA'){
                   $productFlavours = '';
                }
                $result['quoteItemData'][$i]['flavor'] = $productFlavours;
                json_encode($result);
                }
        }
        return $result;
        }

}
```

Then override the details.js(vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/item/details.js) file and add below code

```
define(
[
    'uiComponent'
],
function (Component) {
    "use strict";
    var quoteItemData = window.checkoutConfig.quoteItemData;
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/summary/item/details'
        },
        quoteItemData: quoteItemData,
        getValue: function(quoteItem) {
            return quoteItem.name;
        },
        getItemFlavor: function(quoteItem) {
            var itemProduct = this.getItemProduct(quoteItem.item_id);
            return itemProduct.flavor;
        },
        getItemProduct: function(item_id) {
            var itemElement = null;
            _.each(this.quoteItemData, function(element, index) {
                if (element.item_id == item_id) {
                    itemElement = element;
                }
            });
            return itemElement;
        }

    });
}

);
```

In details.html add below code

```
<span class="product-item-new" data-bind="text: getItemFlavor($parent)"></span>
```

Comment: For some reason this doesn't seem to show on the second page of the checkout, but works great on the first... any thoughts?

Comment: Yes Alex. I have fixed it today. I will update the answer by tomorrow.

Comment: @Alex check my updated answer.

Comment: That's great - the last line in your update needs to be getItemFlavor. One quetsion, how do I make this available inside cart-items.html inside the `ko foreach: getItems()` loop - your last solution was available there, but this one isn't and I'm not sure why.

Comment: yes....You are right. I will check and get back to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61283/discussion-between-sejal-shah-and-alex-hadley).

Comment: Ok, so we got it to showing on the first page of checkout, and to be available in the getItems loop, but if anyone knows how to have it still available in the second page of checkout, that would be great.

Comment: This works to get the configurable product parent data, but how can we get the simple product's attribute data?