# Magento2 - How can I display a product attribute value in Order Summary block?

Tags: magento2, php, magento-2.1, knockoutjs

I am trying to display a product attribute value - SKU in Order Summary block.

I have found the template where it is displayed: `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/item/details.html`, on line 15.

```
   <div class="iwd-details-qty details-qty">
            <span class="value" data-bind="text: $parent.qty"></span>
        </div>
```

e.g. `$parent.product_sku` or `$parent.[any-attribute-code]`  outputs an empty string.
But in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php` have `product_sku`

```
 protected function doGetItemData()
    {
        $imageHelper = $this->imageHelper->init($this->getProductForThumbnail(), 'mini_cart_product_thumbnail');
        return [
     ...........
            'product_sku' => $this->item->getProduct()->getSku(),
          ........
            ],
    }
```

How can I get the value of `product_sku`?

P.S.
I also found this question - [Magento2 - How can I display a product attribute value in Order Summary block?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119789/magento2-how-can-i-display-a-product-attribute-value-in-order-summary-block/163844#163844) and [Add custom product attribute to checkout summary Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132746/add-custom-product-attribute-to-checkout-summary-magento-2?rq=1)
But on this question no answer.

Anybody knows how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a plugin for that. I wanted to add product flavor to order summary. This is the way I created a plugin and achieved what I wanted.

Vendor = Sejal

Files you need to create:

1. Registration.php : app\code\Sejal\Flavor\registration.php
2. di.xml : app\code\Sejal\Flavor\etc\di.xml
3. module.xml : app\code\Sejal\Flavor\etc\di.xml
4. ConfigProviderPlugin.php : app\code\Sejal\Flavor\Plugin\ConfigProviderPlugin.php
5. details.html : copy of vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\summary\item\details.html

you can override this file in your theme like this

app\design\frontend\Vendor\themename\Magento_Checkout\web\template\summary\item\details.html

Code:
registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Sejal_Flavor',
    __DIR__
);
```

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
        <plugin name="AddAttPlug" type="Sejal\Flavor\Plugin\ConfigProviderPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Sejal_Flavor" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

ConfigProviderPlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace Sejal\Flavor\Plugin;

class ConfigProviderPlugin extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{

    public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, array $result)
    {

        $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        for($i=0;$i<count($items);$i++){

            $quoteId = $items[$i]['item_id'];
            $quote = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item')->load($quoteId);
            $productId = $quote->getProductId();
            $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
            $productFlavours = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('flavors')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);         
            if($productFlavours == 'No' || $productFlavours == 'NA'){
                $productFlavours = '';
            }
            $items[$i]['flavor'] = $productFlavours;
        }
        $result['totalsData']['items'] = $items;
        return $result;
    }

}
```

details.html

Copy vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\summary\item\details.html in theme and add

```
<div class="product-item-flavor" data-bind="text: $parent.flavor"></div>
```

below

```
<strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="text: $parent.name"></strong>
```

That's it! 
Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, Sejal shah it show on shipping page but disappear on payment page.
why?

Comment: Check update in my answer here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119789/magento2-how-can-i-display-a-product-attribute-value-in-order-summary-block/178395#178395