# Magento2: How to add product description to shopping cart and checkout page?

Tags: magento-2.1, product-attribute, shopping-cart

For shopping cart, I added the following code to

`app/design/frontend/VendorName/custom/Magento_checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml`

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getDescription(), 'description') ?>
```

But it is not displaying the description. How to add product description to shopping cart and checkout page?

Comment: I got the description for product in shopping cart page with the following code. What template to override for checkout page?                                                                                                                                                 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $productDescription = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId())->getDescription();
                echo $productDescription;

Comment: Let me know whether you have custom theme?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183767/magento-2-display-attribute-on-cart-page/183879#183879

Comment: Here i am considering Smartwave/porto is the theme, Hence place <?php echo $_item->getProduct()->getData('description');?>in your custom theme

Comment: I just saw your suggestion. Thanks for the reply but I got the description on checkout page working partially with @Sejal's suggestion on https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163848/magento2-how-can-i-display-a-product-attribute-value-in-order-summary-block. Currently it is displaying the description after the page loads and then the order summary part is getting refreshed and the description is no longer seen.Would you know what the issue is n how to fix it? I don't have the points to comment on sejal's answer.

Comment: I figured out why it is refreshing. There's some other ups shipping code in order summary that is causing it to load

Comment: Actually I have given code for displaying the product attribute data in the cart page might be it will work on  checkout page also. Let me where u want to show the description for the product in the checkout page please post screen shot in the comment section so that I can check the same... Please confirm whether u tryied my code and confirm me whether it has been working or not....thanks

Comment: No, I  haven't tried your code

Comment: just try and get back with your comments so that i can guide u thanks

Answer (score 4):

Please follow the below steps:

> Step 1: description is an default attribute for the product hence call the same from your custom module as shown below.

**/app/etc/NameSpace/ModuleName/etc/catalog_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
 <group name="quote_item">
     <attribute name="description"/>
 </group>
</config>
```

> Step 2: Go to below path 
>   **/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml**

use like this `<?php echo $_item->getProduct()->getData('description');?>`

> Step 3: Clear cache and page cache and go to frontend & check the
>   same.

Answer (score 1):

Go to below path

> /app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml

`$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();`

```
 $productDescription = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($‌​_item->getProductId(‌​))->getDescription()‌​; 
echo $productDescription;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's too easy to get product fields on the checkout cart page with the object manager

There are two ways to get details

1. Using Object Manager
2. Using the override method

Here I'm showing you a direct method from the Object manager

1. Please go to below path in your root magento 2

```
app/design/frontend/VendorName/custom/Magento_checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml
```

2. Using the below the line you can get the description of the product

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productDescription = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId())->getDescription();
```

If you want to get any field of the product than just replace with the **Description** in the above code.