# Adding custom attribute to checkout order summary not reflecting on payment page

Tags: magento2, checkout, product-attribute, order-summary

I wanted to add product flavor to order summary. I achieved this in following way.

Files:

1. Registration.php : app\code\Sejal\Flavor\registration.php
2. di.xml : app\code\Sejal\Flavor\etc\di.xml
3. module.xml : app\code\Sejal\Flavor\etc\di.xml
4. ConfigProviderPlugin.php : app\code\Sejal\Flavor\Plugin\ConfigProviderPlugin.php
5. details.html : app\design\frontend\Vendor\themename\Magento_Checkout\web\template\summary\item\details.html

**registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Sejal_Flavor',
    __DIR__
);
```

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
        <plugin name="AddAttPlug" type="Sejal\Flavor\Plugin\ConfigProviderPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Sejal_Flavor" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

**ConfigProviderPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace Sejal\Flavor\Plugin;

class ConfigProviderPlugin extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{

    public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, array $result)
    {

        $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        for($i=0;$i<count($items);$i++){

            $quoteId = $items[$i]['item_id'];
            $quote = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item')->load($quoteId);
            $productId = $quote->getProductId();
            $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
            $productFlavours = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('flavors')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);         
            if($productFlavours == 'No' || $productFlavours == 'NA'){
                $productFlavours = '';
            }
            $items[$i]['flavor'] = $productFlavours;
        }
        $result['totalsData']['items'] = $items;
        return $result;
    }

}
```

**details.html**

Copied `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\summary\item\details.html` in theme and added

```
<div class="product-item-flavor" data-bind="text: $parent.flavor"></div>
```

below

```
<strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="text: $parent.name"></strong>
```

It reflected on checkout shipping information page. However, I can not see flavor on payment page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution!

Updated **ConfigProviderPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace Abbottstore\Flavor\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface as QuoteItemRepository;


class ConfigProviderPlugin extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    private $checkoutSession;
    private $quoteItemRepository;
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
        QuoteItemRepository $quoteItemRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->quoteItemRepository = $quoteItemRepository;
    }


    public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, array $result)
    {
            $quoteId = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId();            
            if ($quoteId) {            
                $itemOptionCount = count($result['totalsData']['items']);
                $quoteItems = $this->quoteItemRepository->getList($quoteId);
                $isbnOptions = array();
                foreach ($quoteItems as $index => $quoteItem) {
                    $quoteItemId = $quoteItem['item_id'];
                    $isbnOptions[$quoteItemId] = $quoteItem['isbn'];               
                }

                for ($i=0; $i < $itemOptionCount; $i++) {
                $quoteParentId = $result['totalsData']['items'][$i]['item_id'];
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $productId = $result['quoteItemData'][$i]['product']['entity_id'];
                $productObj = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

                $productFlavours = $productObj->getResource()->getAttribute('flavors')->getFrontend()->getValue($productObj);         
                if($productFlavours == 'No' || $productFlavours == 'NA'){
                   $productFlavours = '';
                }
                $result['quoteItemData'][$i]['flavor'] = $productFlavours;
                json_encode($result);
                }
        }
        return $result;
        }

}
```

Override **details.js** (vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/item/details.js) and wrote this code.

```
define(
[
    'uiComponent'
],
function (Component) {
    "use strict";
    var quoteItemData = window.checkoutConfig.quoteItemData;
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/summary/item/details'
        },
        quoteItemData: quoteItemData,
        getValue: function(quoteItem) {
            return quoteItem.name;
        },
        getItemFlavor: function(quoteItem) {
            var itemProduct = this.getItemProduct(quoteItem.item_id);
            return itemProduct.flavor;
        },
        getItemProduct: function(item_id) {
            var itemElement = null;
            _.each(this.quoteItemData, function(element, index) {
                if (element.item_id == item_id) {
                    itemElement = element;
                }
            });
            return itemElement;
        }

    });
}

);
```

and in **details.html** added this line

```
<span class="product-item-new" data-bind="text: getItemFlavor($parent)"></span>
```

Comment: i have made this changes so now checkout page is not working.

Comment: @sejal can you have idea about 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/291743/68695

Comment: It show on Checkout #shipping page but when select shipping method and step next on #payment page then custom attribute disappear from summary section.
Why

Comment: Check updated answer here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119789/magento2-how-can-i-display-a-product-attribute-value-in-order-summary-block/178395#178395

Comment: could you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59243164/enable-payment-gateway-for-particular-products-magento-2

Comment: It works on Amasty_OneStepCheckout with Magento 2.4.2p1. Thanks!