# Magento2 How to Discount Description add on Checkout order summary

Tags: magento2, discount, magento2.3.2, order-summary

I Want to add **Coupon Description** in **Order Summary**

[image]
[image]

I have to Find the file here

> app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[theme]/Magento_SalesRule/web/template/cart/totals/discount.html

```
<!-- ko if: isDisplayed() -->
<tr class="totals discount">
    <th class="mark" scope="row">
        <span class="title" data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span>
        <span class="discount coupon" data-bind="text: getCouponCode()"></span>
    </th>
    <td class="amount">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': name}"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Here Hoe can I get **Coupon Description**

**Note:** I have added coupon description in Backend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at Magento default:

```
vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Plugin/CartTotalRepository.php
```

As we can see, `coupon_label` is an extension attribute.

So, we can follow this rule. Create our coupon description extension attribute.

app/code/Vendor/Quote/etc/extension_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsInterface">
        <attribute code="coupon_description" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Quote/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository">
        <plugin name="coupon_description_plugin" type="Vendor\Quote\Plugin\CartTotalRepository" />
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Quote/Plugin/CartTotalRepository.php

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Quote\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsExtensionFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsInterface;
use Magento\SalesRule\Api\RuleRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon;

/**
 * Class CartTotalRepository
 * @package Magento\SalesRule\Plugin
 */
class CartTotalRepository
{
    /**
     * @var TotalsExtensionFactory
     */
    private $extensionFactory;

    /**
     * @var RuleRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $ruleRepository;

    /**
     * @var Coupon
     */
    private $coupon;

    /**
     * CartTotalRepository constructor.
     * @param TotalsExtensionFactory $extensionFactory
     * @param RuleRepositoryInterface $ruleRepository
     * @param Coupon $coupon
     */
    public function __construct(
        TotalsExtensionFactory $extensionFactory,
        RuleRepositoryInterface $ruleRepository,
        Coupon $coupon
    ) {
        $this->extensionFactory = $extensionFactory;
        $this->ruleRepository = $ruleRepository;
        $this->coupon = $coupon;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository $subject
     * @param TotalsInterface $result
     * @return TotalsInterface
     *
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function afterGet(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository $subject,
        TotalsInterface $result
    ) {
        if ($result->getExtensionAttributes() === null) {
            $extensionAttributes = $this->extensionFactory->create();
            $result->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        }

        $extensionAttributes = $result->getExtensionAttributes();
        $couponCode = $result->getCouponCode();

        if (empty($couponCode)) {
            return $result;
        }
        $this->coupon->loadByCode($couponCode);
        $ruleId = $this->coupon->getRuleId();

        if (empty($ruleId)) {
            return $result;
        }
        $rule = $this->ruleRepository->getById($ruleId);
        $extensionAttributes->setCouponDescription($rule->getDescription());
        $result->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Check `window.checkoutConfig.totalsData` in browser console:

[image]

**Frontend Part:**

We will use our custom js component and templates

app/code/Vendor/Quote/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Quote/js/view/cart/totals/discount</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/code/Vendor/Quote/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Quote/js/view/summary/discount</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/code/Vendor/Quote/view/frontend/web/js/view/cart/totals/discount.js

```
define([
    'Magento_SalesRule/js/view/summary/discount'
], function (Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Quote/cart/totals/discount'
        },

        getDescription: function() {
            if (!this.totals()) {
                return null;
            }
            if (typeof this.totals()['extension_attributes'] === 'undefined') return null;
            return this.totals()['extension_attributes']['coupon_description'];
        }
    });
});
```

app/code/Vendor/Quote/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/discount.js

```
define([
    'Magento_SalesRule/js/view/summary/discount'
], function (Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Quote/cart/totals/discount'
        },

        getDescription: function() {
            if (!this.totals()) {
                return null;
            }
            if (typeof this.totals()['extension_attributes'] === 'undefined') return null;
            return this.totals()['extension_attributes']['coupon_description'];
        },

        /**
         * @override
         *
         * @returns {Boolean}
         */
        isDisplayed: function () {
            return this.getPureValue() != 0; //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
        }
    });
});
```

app/code/Vendor/Quote/view/frontend/web/template/cart/totals/discount.html

```
<!-- ko if: isDisplayed() -->
<tr class="totals">
    <th colspan="1" style="" class="mark" scope="row">
        <span class="title" data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span>
        <span class="discount coupon" data-bind="text: getCouponLabel()"></span>
        <span class="discount description" data-bind="text: getDescription()"></span>
    </th>
    <td class="amount" data-bind="attr: {'data-th': title}">
        <span><span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

app/code/Vendor/Quote/view/frontend/web/template/summary/discount.html

```
<!-- ko if: isDisplayed() -->
<tr class="totals discount">
    <th class="mark" scope="row">
        <span class="title" data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span>
        <span class="discount coupon" data-bind="text: getCouponCode()"></span>
        <span class="discount description" data-bind="text: getDescription()"></span>
    </th>
    <td class="amount">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': name}"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/discount.js` you need to override this js or create your own. We can get it from `this.totals()`

Comment: Updated the frontend part.

Comment: when coupon code available then description showing but when coupon code not available then not showing rule description : http://prntscr.com/pgdao9

Comment: The coupon description is only available when the coupon is applied. You can change the Js logic to show a default text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99606/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-rakesh-donga).

Answer (score 0):

You can override

```
app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[theme]/Magento_SalesRule/web/template/cart/totals/discount.html and add below code

<span class="description" data-bind="text: getCouponDescription()"></span>
```

in your theme and also override below js as well

> app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[theme]/Magento_SalesRule/js/view/summary/discount.js

add function like getCouponDescription and add below code

getCouponCode: function () {
        if (!this.totals()) {
            return null;
        }

```
    return this.totals()['coupon_description'];
},
```

add extension attribute in your quote api for coupon_description

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface">
        <attribute code="coupon_description" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

and create plugin

```
$extensionAttributes = $cart->getExtensionAttributes();
        $quoteId = $cart->getId();
        $couponDescription = "Your coupon descriptin code"
        $extensionAttributes->setCouponDescription($couponDescription);
        $cart->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
```

Hope it should works

Comment: ok let me try but i can not understand this point 
 extension attribute in your quote api for coupon_description

Comment: Yes you have to add extension_attribute using extension_attributes.xml for quotes.

Comment: can you update code here how can use i have no experiance in `extension_attribute`

Comment: Please check , Hope it work

Comment: Thanks for reply but i want to coupn description dynamic i have added backend in rule

Comment: Yes , This I just given example. here you have to call sales_rule table and get the description dynamically based on rule id or coupon code.

Comment: Hi Bro, Is it worked?

Comment: no it is not worked i think here is half code as per my question

Comment: okay willl write a complete code and share with you in sometime.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to override the SalesRule module's template and JS.

This is how I did it on several of my shops:

In you theme folder create

> Magento_SalesRule/web/template/cart/totals/discount.html

```
<!-- ko if: isDisplayed() -->
<tr class="totals">
    <th colspan="1" style="" class="mark" scope="row">
        <span class="title" data-bind="text: getDiscountLabel()"></span>
        <span class="discount coupon" data-bind="text: getCouponLabel()"></span>
    </th>
    <td class="amount" data-bind="attr: {'data-th': title}">
        <span><span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

> Magento_SalesRule/web/js/view/summary/discount.js

```
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function (Component, quote) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_SalesRule/summary/discount'
        },
        totals: quote.getTotals(),

        /**
         * @return {*|Boolean}
         */
        isDisplayed: function () {
            return this.isFullMode() && this.getPureValue() != 0; //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
        },

        /**
         * @return {*}
         */
        getCouponCode: function () {
            if (!this.totals()) {
                return null;
            }

            return this.totals()['coupon_code'];
        },

        /**
         * @return {*}
         */
        getCouponLabel: function () {
            if (!this.totals()) {
                return null;
            }

            return this.totals()['coupon_label'];
        },

        /**
         * @return {*}
         */
        getDiscountLabel: function () {
            if (!this.totals()) {
                return null;
            }

            return this.totals()['total_segments'][2]['title'];
        },

        /**
         * @return {Number}
         */
        getPureValue: function () {
            var price = 0;

            if (this.totals() && this.totals()['discount_amount']) {
                price = parseFloat(this.totals()['discount_amount']);
            }

            return price;
        },

        /**
         * @return {*|String}
         */
        getValue: function () {
            return this.getFormattedPrice(this.getPureValue());
        }
    });
});
```

Make sure to flush the static files cache and Magento's cache afterwards.

You should then be able to see the label (description) of the discount.

Comment: your code in shipping description showing i want to coupon code description 
http://prntscr.com/pfuu7l ,here showing rule description http://prntscr.com/pfuuuw

Comment: please here check it http://prntscr.com/pfuzwy and i want to coupon code description not shipping description

Comment: The "description" field is used as a description of the rule for administrators. The "Label" field is used for frontend purposes. You should put your cart price rule description in the "label" field https://prnt.sc/pfvwi7

Comment: here i have allready add label so i need below line coupon description

Comment: If you really want the "description" field content, then I believe you would need to override or extend the `fetch` method in `Magento_SalesRule\Model\Quote\Discount.php` and add the description to the cart price rule totals segment. But I haven't done that before, so can't help...

Comment: ok no problem Thanks for help  i have working on this file i will try to get description here