# when coupon code apply and discount amount 0 then coupon not showing in order summery

Tags: discount, magento2.3.2, coupon-codes, order-summary

Coupon code not showing when **discount amount** is **0.00**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I am sorry this is for the admin part. I red the question too fast and didn't realise it was for the frontend. But i will leave the answer here since i think the same logic could apply for the frontend and that you might also want it in the backend.

In vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Totals.php in the function _initTotals you have some code like this :

```
    if ((double)$this->getSource()->getDiscountAmount() != 0) {
        if ($this->getSource()->getDiscountDescription()) {
            $discountLabel = __('Discount (%1)', $this->getSource()->getDiscountDescription());
        } else {
            $discountLabel = __('Discount');
        }
        $this->_totals['discount'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'code' => 'discount',
                'value' => $this->getSource()->getDiscountAmount(),
                'base_value' => $this->getSource()->getBaseDiscountAmount(),
                'label' => $discountLabel,
            ]
        );
    }
```

You have to change the condition for

```
if ((double)$this->getSource()->getDiscountAmount() != 0)
```

To

```
if ($this->getSource()->getDiscountAmount() != null)
```

Now since you should not change this directly in the core you can create an override on the class \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Totals like that :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Order;

class Totals extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Totals
{

    protected function _initTotals()
    {
        parent::_initTotals();

        /**
         * Add discount
         */
        if ($this->getSource()->getDiscountAmount() !== null) {
            if ($this->getSource()->getDiscountDescription()) {
                $discountLabel = __('Discount (%1)', $this->getSource()->getDiscountDescription());
            } else {
                $discountLabel = __('Discount');
            }
            $this->_totals['discount'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                [
                    'code' => 'discount',
                    'value' => $this->getSource()->getDiscountAmount(),
                    'base_value' => $this->getSource()->getBaseDiscountAmount(),
                    'label' => $discountLabel,
                ]
            );
        }


        return $this;
    }
}
```

Edit 2 : For the front end you will have to do the exact same thing but you will have to override the file vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Order/Totals.php instead of vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Totals.php.

Comment: I edited my answer, to override the frontend you have to do the same override but on a different file.

Comment: i want to for frontend and i have use your code as per your suggestion but not working for me

Answer (score 0):

**app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Quote\Discount" type="VENDOR\MODULE\Model\Quote\Discount" />
</config>
```

**app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/Model/Quote/Discount.php**

```
<?php

namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Model\Quote;

class Discount extends \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Quote\Discount
{
    public function fetch(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total)
    {
        $result = null;
        $amount = $total->getDiscountAmount();

        $description = $total->getDiscountDescription();
        $result = [
            'code' => $this->getCode(),
            'title' => strlen($description) ? __('Discount (%1)', $description) : __('Discount'),
            'value' => $amount
        ];

        return $result;
    }
}
```

you need to override **module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/template/cart/totals/discount.html** into your theme. and add below code into it

```
<tr class="totals">
    <th colspan="1" style="" class="mark" scope="row">
        <span class="title" data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span>
        <span class="discount coupon" data-bind="text: getCouponLabel()"></span>
    </th>
    <td class="amount" data-bind="attr: {'data-th': title}">
        <span><span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

i removed below lines from **discount.html** file

```
<!-- ko if: isDisplayed() --> and <!-- /ko -->
```

do same with this file also **module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/template/summary/discount.html** for checkout page

you will get your result :D

Comment: i have tested this code in magento2.3.3, it is working as per your need, you don't need to change anything

Comment: you can ignore if(1) condition, updated the answer

Comment: i need only checkout summery page nothing cart page

Comment: still you need to override Discount class, and removed isDisplayed from module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/template/summary/discount.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103402/discussion-between-rakesh-donga-and-hiren).

Comment: i have a check after adding my code into your module, Discount class is not override using preference, once you solve this issue it will work

Comment: you have implement in code?

Comment: yes, you can check directly in Magento\SalesRule\Model\Quote\Discount if it is working or not

Comment: There is no need to override Magento\SalesRule\Model\Quote\Discount. If you DID need to change the outcome of the fetch function you would use an after plugin. It is not good practice to use preference when plugins and other methods are available. It WILL come back to haunt you.

Comment: i agree Shawn Abramson, i'm just suggesting the way to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding below js in your theme/module

> vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/js/view/cart/totals/discount.js

In this  file there is below code

```
isDisplayed: function () {
    return this.getPureValue() != 0; //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
}
```

Try replacing it with

```
isDisplayed: function () {
    return this.getCouponCode() != null; //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
}
```

I have not tested the code but you can give it a try.

**Update**

For checkout page summary try overriding same method in below file

> vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/discount.js

Your final method should be as below-

```
isDisplayed: function () {
    return this.isFullMode() && this.getCouponCode() != null; //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
},
```

Comment: Thank you for answer your code is working in cart page fine right but i need in checkout order summery (https://prnt.sc/qov49o)

Comment: i have implement on this file but not working for me i have try that before when you have answer and may here here return two functions https://prnt.sc/qov9af

Comment: does it work when you remove the `isFullMode` condition and add the coupon code condition?

Comment: i have try that but not working ....

Comment: it should work, please check if file is not override by any other module Or you have override file properly

Comment: can you update your answer for checkout page order summery related? then easy for me

Comment: hi @RakeshDonga try my answer it will work on both pages

Comment: @Piyush i have implement your code but just coupon code description showing coupon code is missing https://prnt.sc/qovqm4

Comment: both description and coupon code are shown from same html , so please check your html from theme/module or check you css rule applied there

Comment: @Piyush i have use this module and i have implement your code in this module js please check it : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/291999/68695

Comment: @Piyush my custom extension file like this way ; https://prnt.sc/qovwwj,https://prnt.sc/qovx8m

Comment: @Piyush my side only coupon description showing not other coupon code showing when your code apply