# Apply Discount and Cancel Discount is not work on my Custom Tab

Tags: magento2, discount, coupon, tabs

I have created a Module in which Created some custom Tab and on that tab i have added discount coupon code.
I have added

```
<div class="payment-option _collapsible opc-payment-additional discount-code"
 data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': '_active'}}">
<div class="payment-option-title field choice" data-role="title">
    <span class="action action-toggle" id="block-discount-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2">
        <!-- ko i18n: 'Apply Discount Code'--><!-- /ko -->
    </span>
</div>
<div class="payment-option-content" data-role="content">
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->
    <form class="form form-discount" id="discount-form">
        <div class="payment-option-inner">
            <div class="field">
                <label class="label" for="discount-code">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Enter discount code'"></span>
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input-text"
                           type="text"
                           id="discount-code"
                           name="discount_code"
                           data-validate="{'required-entry':true}"
                           data-bind="value: couponCode, attr:{disabled:isApplied() , placeholder: $t('Enter discount code')} " />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <!-- ko ifnot: isApplied() -->
                    <button class="action action-apply" type="submit" data-bind="'value': $t('Apply Discount'), click: apply">
                        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Apply Discount'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                    </button>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko if: isApplied() -->
                    <button class="action action-cancel" type="submit" data-bind="'value': $t('Cancel'), click: cancel">
                        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Cancel coupon'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                    </button>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('captcha') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

It shows discount coupan but it doesn't work
[image]

As i have shared image where i have added the coupan code.
How should it worked or I have skip some step?

Comment: check the response from your controller

Comment: I didn't create controller fot that discount coupan.
Is there a need for that if i create one what should i implement in it. Because i just add html for discount code in my steps html file.@Chikku

Comment: then how are you sending data?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/291743/magento2-how-to-discount-description-add-on-checkout-order-summary

Comment: I have added my code on https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/318523/how-to-add-discount-coupon-code-on-custom-tab-in-magento-2
will you please check i want to add discount code on my custom tab how will i do it ?

Comment: you need to write a logic for things to work in php file

Comment: so i need to create or use API for that discount coupan work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111353/discussion-between-prits-and-chikku).