# How to add custom attributes to checkout summary magento2.4

Tags: product-attribute, custom-attributes, magento2.4.1, checkout-page

I am trying to display a product attribute value

I have found the template where it is displayed:

vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/item/details.html

I override this file in my theme.

app\design\frontend\Vendor\themename\Magento_Checkout\web\template\summary\item\details.html

How can I get the value of an attribute to display?

Comment: what is your attribute_code?

Comment: Attribute code :Custom_attr

Comment: Follow https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/181244/90013 this link

Comment: I tried but not working