# Magento 2: custom attribute value disappear after page load in order summery checkout page. how to solve?

Tags: magento2

I have been making modifications to an existing Magento project. I want to add custom attribute to the product in Checkout page's order summary section. For this, I created a plugin following the answer in Magento2 - [How can I display a product attribute value in Order Summary block?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163848/magento2-how-can-i-display-a-product-attribute-value-in-order-summary-block)
[image]

After page load completes my custom attribute is not present.
[image]

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.....!

Below is my magento2 Code

### di.xml

### [image]

### Module.xml

### [image]

ConfigProviderPlugin.php

---

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Checkout\Plugin;

class ConfigProviderPlugin extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{

    public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, array $result)
    {

        $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        for($i=0;$i<count($items);$i++){
            $qty = $items[$i]['qty'];

            $quoteId = $items[$i]['item_id'];
            $quote = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item')->load($quoteId);
            $productId = $quote->getProductId();
            $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
            $box_per_lens = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('box_per_lens')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);   
            $use_quantity_type = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('use_quantity_type')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
            $quantity_type = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('quantity_type')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);         
            $quantity_type1 ='';
            $box_per_lens1 ='';
            $qData = '';
            if($use_quantity_type == 'No' || $use_quantity_type == 'NA'){
               $quantity_type1='Quantity';
               $qData = $qty.' '.$quantity_type1;

            }else{
                if($quantity_type == 'No' || $quantity_type == 'NA'){

                   $quantity_type1 ='';
                }else{
                     $quantity_type1 = $quantity_type;
                }
                if($box_per_lens == 'No' || $box_per_lens == 'NA'){
                    $box_per_lens1 = "";
                     $qData = $qty.' '.$quantity_type1;
                 }
                 else{
                     $box_per_lens1  = $box_per_lens;
                      $qData = $qty.' '.$quantity_type1.'('.($qty*$box_per_lens1).' lenses)';
                 }

            }


            $items[$i]['flavor'] = "call66";
            $items[$i]['qtyData'] = $qData;
        } 


        $result['totalsData']['items'] = $items;
        return $result;
    }

}
```

details.html

### Override location:  app/design/frontend/Theme/luma/Mageplaza_Osc/web/template/container/summary/item/details.html

```
<td class="a-left product ">


    <div class="product-item-detail">
        <div class="product-item-inner">
            <div class="product-item-name-block">
                <!-- ko if: getProductUrl($parent) -->
                <a data-bind="attr:{href: getProductUrl($parent)}" target="_blank">
                    <strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="text: $parent.name"></strong>
                </a>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: getProductUrl($parent)-->
                <strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="text: $parent.name"></strong>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- <span class="product-item-qty" data-bind="text: $parent.qty"></span> -->
                <span class="product-item-qtyData" data-bind="text: $parent.qtyData"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- ko if: isItemAvailable($parent.item_id) -->
    <div class="gift-message-item-content">
        <div class="gift-message-item" data-bind="attr: { id: 'item' +$parent.item_id, title: giftMessageItemsTitleHover},click: loadGiftMessageItem.bind($data,$parent.item_id)">
            <i class="fa fa-gift fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div style="display: none" data-bind="attr: { id: 'item' + $parent.item_id,title: $parent.name},afterRender: setModalElement">
            <div class="gift-options-content">
                <div class="fieldset">
                    <div class="field field-from col-mp mp-6">
                        <!-- ko ifnot: window.checkoutConfig.oscConfig.isUsedMaterialDesign -->
                        <label for="gift-message-whole-from" class="label">
                            <span data-bind="i18n: 'From:'"></span>
                        </label>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        <div class="control input-field">
                            <input type="text" id="gift-message-whole-from" class="input-text" required>
                            <!-- ko if: window.checkoutConfig.oscConfig.isUsedMaterialDesign -->
                            <label for="gift-message-whole-from" class="label">
                                <span data-bind="i18n: 'From:'"></span>
                            </label>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field field-to col-mp mp-6">
                        <!-- ko ifnot: window.checkoutConfig.oscConfig.isUsedMaterialDesign -->
                        <label for="gift-message-whole-to" class="label">
                            <span data-bind="i18n: 'To:'"></span>
                        </label>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        <div class="control input-field">
                            <input type="text" id="gift-message-whole-to" class="input-text" required>
                            <!-- ko if: window.checkoutConfig.oscConfig.isUsedMaterialDesign -->
                            <label for="gift-message-whole-to" class="label">
                                <span data-bind="i18n: 'To:'"></span>
                            </label>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field text col-mp mp-12">
                        <!-- ko ifnot: window.checkoutConfig.oscConfig.isUsedMaterialDesign -->
                        <label for="gift-message-whole-message" class="label">
                            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Message:'"></span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="control">
                            <textarea id="gift-message-whole-message" class="input-text" rows="5" cols="10"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        <!-- ko if: window.checkoutConfig.oscConfig.isUsedMaterialDesign -->
                        <div class="control">
                            <textarea id="gift-message-whole-message" class="input-text" rows="3" cols="10" data-bind="attr:{placeholder: $t('Message')}"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <button type="submit" name="update" class="action update"  data-bind="click: updateGiftMessageItem.bind($data,$parent.item_id)">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="primary">
                    <button type="submit" name="delete" class="action delete" data-bind="click: deleteGiftMessageItem.bind($data,$parent.item_id)">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Delete'"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</td>
<!-- <td class="a-center details-qty">
    <div class="qty-wrapper">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button-action minus" data-bind="click: minusQty" title="Minus"></a>
        <div class="qty-wrap">
            <input class="item_qty input-text update value" name="item_qty"  data-bind="value: $parent.qty, attr: {id: $parent.item_id}, event: {change: changeQty}" />
        </div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button-action plus" data-bind="click: plusQty" title="Plus"></a>
    </div>
</td> -->
<td class="a-center subtotal">
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('after_details') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</td>
<td class="a-center last button-remove">
    <div class="remove-wrapper">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button-action remove" data-bind="click:function(){removeItem($parent.item_id)}"></a>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Can you guys please help me?

Comment: Post your code to check the problem.

Comment: I have posted code in above Question...

Comment: Please check...

Comment: How did you solve this issue? I am also facing the same issue ..

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue, Am trying to get the product short description.
It appears while loading and disappears after it fully loaded.

Below is my plugin function

```
public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, array $result){

    $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    for($i=0;$i<count($items);$i++){

        $quoteId = $items[$i]['item_id'];
        $quote = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item')->load($quoteId);
        $productId = $quote->getProductId();
        $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
        $productShortDesc = $product->getShortDescription();        

        $items[$i]['product_shortdesc'] = $productShortDesc;

    }
    $result['totalsData']['items'] = $items;
        return $result;
}
```

In details.html
Am calling using data-bind

```
 <span class="product-desc" data-bind="html: $parent.product_shortdesc"></span>
```

Did anyone find the solution for this?

Comment: I tried https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119789/magento2-how-can-i-display-a-product-attribute-value-in-order-summary-block/163844#163844